# Присвоить новое значение экземпляру класса через функцию этого класса (Python)

Tags: python, ооп, дерево, объекты

Я строю из классов некое подобие дерева. У каждого экземпляра класса (кроме корня) имеется предок, и переменная, содержащая экземпляр класса, должна при вызове функции, вроде go_upper (которая является методом класса) поменять значение на предка. Объясняю плохо, уж извините. Может будет понятнее, если взглянуть на пример кода.

Вот как это приблизительно выглядит:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent


    def go_upper(self):
        self = self.parent

class _RootTest(Test):
    def __init__(self):
         pass

first = _RootTest()
second = Test(first)
second.go_upper() # Переменной second должно присвоиться first
```

Как можно реализовать что-то такое?

Comment: Что значит, изменить значение экземпляра класса? У него нет значения, это объект, который имеен аттрибуты, методы. В данном случае вы просто в области видимости метода `go_upper` переопределяете имя `self`.

Comment: Я неправильно выразился. Я пытаюсь изменить значение переменной, содержащей экземпляр класса

Comment: Тогда непонятно, зачем вообще нужен метод класса. Вам же всегда будет известен экземпляр класса, ссылку на который вы хотите получить.

Comment: Может быть, лучше вместо этого делать second = second.parent

Comment: Бывает такой момент, когда не хочется сделать нормально, а хочется сделать красиво. Думаю, это тот случай. Метод класса нужен для красоты, ничего существенного он не делает. Как описали выше, должно производиться то же действие, что и при second = second.parent. Если сделать отдельный метод под это - увеличится читабельность кода